# Stair riser renovation

Tags: stairs, renovation

I am looking to renovate this staircase. The bottom two risers are in bad shape. I was thinking of sticking plywood over them. Is this a good idea, any other suggestions?[image]

Comment: They do look rough, are they stable or do they move when being stepped on? If so they may need to be rebuilt.

Comment: Are the brackets holding the treads, or the risers, in place?

Comment: @Huesmann , I missed that obvious detail. those are a good indicator of "moving parts". My gut feeling is that the lower section needs to be rebuilt. I see on the lower riser that is missing the curved veneer that the bull nose has solid cut blocking for support there, so I would hope. It looks like they could be rebuilt to their former glory.

Comment: It does look like very nice wood was used on the stairs.  Depending on your design likes, refinishing/rebuilding those stairs, might be worth the time and money.

Comment: Somebody invested a lot of energy into making those stairs. I can't bring myself to suggest quick fixes that will erase that work. I think that I see veneer peeling off the second riser. My grandfather had a solid oak desk with a cherry veneer on top. It's possible that you would discover hardwood behind that peeling veneer, where you could finish that wood. You can buy thin hardwood veneers to wrap around the sound, old surface, e.g. https://www.rockler.com/wood/veneer. It can take tighter bends with the grain running perpendicular to the bend.